# Is it possible that matter mass of a star more than total gravitational mass?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass-energy, stars, neutron-stars

Matter mass of  a star  can be found from

$$M_\rho =\frac{1}{2} \int \rho r^2 dr .$$

On the other hand, there is also gravitational mass of a star in the Schwarzchild metric

$$ 1- \frac{2M}{r}.$$

My question is that it is possible the case $M_\rho \gt M $?

Comment: See e.g. [Komar mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komar_mass).

Comment: How do you define $\rho$? Is it a mass density?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gravitational mass of a neutron star is *less* than the sum of the rest masses of all the baryons that make it up.

The gravitational mass is what determines the space curvature and must include all mass-energy terms - that is you have to include the energy of the constituents in the calculation, both their kinetic energy, pressure **and gravitational potential energy**.

For a bound star the sum of these latter items is *negative*, and in the case of a neutron star, can be significant fraction of the rest mass.

Thus in the terms you have defined $M_{\rho} > M$.

Comment: Judging by his comments under my response, the OP seems to mean $\rho$ to be the energy density of the object, rather than its mass density. Using that definition, $M_\rho=M$.

Comment: @probably_someone No, I think not. The energy density would not usually (never) include the negative gravitational potential energy and that is why the gravitational mass is lowered.

Comment: You're right. Deleting my answer, as it is off-topic.